# Every Umbraco POST redirects to Login

Tags: authentication, umbraco

Installed Umbraco, attempting to change anything redirects me to login.  I'm on a shared hosting site, I'm Full Trust...and clueless...

Any ideas?  It's the Umbraco V5 Beta 1 install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried considering rights to  give full control to Network service and IUSR.

Please provide more details if this is still not resolved.

Comment: I'm on a shared hosting site, I don't have permissions to adjust anything there.

Comment: This might be the issue. In Beta version you may need to give the persmissions.